# How do I get rid of these un-calculated parts in Cell Fracture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've tried to recalculate normals, and also tried a solidify modifier. But, cannot seem to get cell fracture to work without having pieces that aren't calculated, meaning, unfinished pieces just sticking out of the object. Here are my settings, the mesh in edit mode and the object with cell fracture. I've tried many variations. Any help would be great!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want the object to break without having big chunks of mesh uncalculated sticking out of it